# Game Audio Podcasts/Vidcasts

Tags: gameaudio, podcasts, media

There has been a post for podcasts on SSD before, but I wanted to thread game audio media.

Video-casting has been popular for a bit, now that we have programs that host the content for quick download onto smart phones. iTunes, Vuze, and others are pretty solid for this.

So far I have found these:

Podcasts:

- GameAudio Podcast - Video Game Audio
- 1Up.com - "The Sound Test" - Video
  Game Music

Vidcasts:

- Machinima - "The Art of the Game" -
  Game Audio and Design
- Soundworks Collection - Select
  Episodes on Game Audio

I want to open this up to everyone and let people tag their own game audio casting they keep up with - The more we listen, the more we learn!

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

http://designingsound.tv/

and filter it by Game Audio.

Answer (score 1):

While not dedicated to game audio, the Irrational Behaviour podcast by Irrational Games is brilliant for an inside look at the industry. They have great production values and the content is very well informed. They have done a dedicated episode on game sound design and do constantly talk about how importent it is.

http://irrationalgames.com/insider/irrational-behavior/